# How do I open a click package?

Tags: click-packages

I created a small app with the Ubuntu SDK and packaged it into a click package. I am curious about what is in it. How can I open it?

The Archive Manager says it does not recognize it and the Ubuntu Software Center (Ubuntu Desktop 13.10) reports that the file could not be opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like .deb packages Click packages are `ar` (not `tar`!) archives so you can unpack them on the command line using

```
ar x file_name
```

There's a [specification for the Click file format at readthedocs.org](http://click.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but I don't know if it is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the .click to have a .ar extension, then file-roller will open it. The click package contains

- `_click-binary` - contains the version number of the click packaging, "0.4"
- `debian-binary` - contains the version number of the deb file
  format it is based on "2.0"
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29
- `control.tar.gz` - contains the manifest, md5 sums of the files in the package and some
  other bits and bobs. If your content changes then the md5 sums will need to be updated.
- `data.tar.gz` - contains the meat of your content,
  this will typically end up in
  /opt/click.ubuntu.com/yourapp.yournamespace/version/

You are best off using the click build tools and SDK to construct click packages rather than manually putting together all the bits.